# ERROR: "*.exe is not a valid Win32 application." 64-bit executable on Windows XP SP2 x64 on 64-bit machine

Tags: windows, windows-xp, 64-bit, win32

I'm using Windows XP SP2 Pro x64 on a 64-bit machine. Default windows services and applications (including IE8) run in 64-bit mode as seen in Task Manager. Yet 3rd party 64-bit executable applications won't start.

Applications were executed from internal HDD (3.5" Seagate 700GB) (C:) and External (2.5" WD My passport 2TB) (D:), so it can't be the hardware, nor file corruption.

Happens with every 64-bit application "*.exe is not a valid Win32 application." as if it was a 16-bit app or system was 32-bit, which is not the case.

I suspect they might be blocked by the system, but I couldn't find where to change it. Anyone knows what's the problem? Thanks in advance.

---

[Visual Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvwga.jpg)

---

Comment: Are you sure the 64-bit executables you are using are meant for [XP Pro x64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_Professional_x64_Edition), not [XP 64-bit edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP_editions#Windows_XP_64-Bit_Edition). Despite the similar names, they have completely different 64-bit executable formats.

Comment: Those apps run on any other x64 system, win7, 8, 10, all of them. As I understand, XP Pro x64 is AMD64 variant, which means it's same as Windows 7 I had previously, on which they worked..

Comment: Does the properties box of the .exe have an "Unblock" button?

Comment: @DawnBenton, no, all of them were unblocked, I checked before executing them.